# Guessing the extract ratio in Tesseract-OCR

Tags: tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract-OCR, and I need to know the % of text that's been extracted. Is there a way to know this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the API method: `int Recognize(ETEXT_DESC* monitor);` Tesseract updates monitor with the progress in some way.

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/trunk/api/baseapi.h?spec=svn1050&r=1046
http://tesseract-ocr.repairfaq.org/structETEXT__DESC.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/W9J_3oe8le8